# sort array by sizes with price attached in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Ok, this is what i'm trying to do, i have 3 sets of arrays. All these values are coming from mysql database and go stright into these arrays.

`sizetype[]` and `price[]` `saleprice[]`

This how the database looks. There is a brand and it has a number of sizes and prices for those sizes, also if a `saleprice exists`, i want to only use the `saleprice` and eleminate the `price` from the outputted list.

```
sizetype | price | saleprice
========   =====   =========

15 Gal   | 35.99 | 34.99

13 Gal   | 32.98 | 29.99

7.5 Gal  | 16.99 |
```

So as far as the sizetype goes

```
$sizetype array('15 Gal', '13 Gal', '7.5 Gal');
```

now the way i originally had it sort the list was using this method:

```
sort($sizetype, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

and it worked just fine, but now my problem is when i print the sorted size, the prices are obviously messed up, cause i only sorted the `sizetype[]`. I'm assuming this is going to require a multidimensional array, but i'm really not used to using them.

If my solution is to use a multi-deminsional array in this, how would i do it, THEN sort my `sizetype[]` and insert into an array that i can output in a `foreach()` loop (example)

```
sizetype | price
======== | =====

7.5 Gal | 16.99 

13 Gal  | 29.99

15 Gal  | 34.99
```

If this is confusing, ill try to redo it and explain it better, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$newarray = array();
foreach($sizetype as $ind=>$val){

    $newarray[$val] = (isset($saleprice[$ind]) && $saleprice[$ind]!='')? $saleprice[$ind] : $price[$ind] ;  //checking if value exists in $saleprice, if not take $price value
}
ksort($newarray,SORT_NUMERIC); //sorting array in ascending order of keys
var_dump($newarray);

//Displaying
echo 'sizetype | price<br>';
echo '===== | =====<br>';
foreach($newarray as $key=>$val){
    echo $key. " | " .$val."<br>";

}
```

## Explanation:

I'm having a new array `$newarray[]` to keep the matched elements together.

Now in the `foreach()` loop:

`foreach($sizetype as $ind=>$val){` `//$sizetype[]` holds the values like `'7.5 Gal', '13 Gal'..` like you mentioned in your question

`$newarray[$val] = (isset($saleprice[$ind]) && $saleprice[$ind]!='')? $saleprice[$ind] : $price[$ind] ;`  I'll break this down but before that, know that `$saleprice[]` is another array that includes values like `34.99`, `29.99` (from your question)

Now `$newarray[$val]` will be for instance `$newarray['15 Gal']`

`(isset($saleprice[$ind]) && $saleprice[$ind]!='')? $saleprice[$ind] : $price[$ind] ;` 
This translates to - if `$saleprice[0]` is set and value is not empty, then `$newarray['15 Gal'] = $saleprice[0]` else take the value of `$price[0]`

This is same as writing:

```
if(isset($saleprice[$ind]) && $saleprice[$ind]!=''){
   $newarray[$val] = $saleprice[$ind];
}
else
{
   $newarray[$val] = $price[$ind];
}
```

Thus as this keeps repeating, it will check if value exists in `$saleprice` or it will take the value of `$price`

I am not very good at explaining codes, but feel free to ask if you need more details.

Comment: can you please explain how your foreach loop is working in detail, im very lost.

Comment: **+1** , for the neat and detailed explanation !

Comment: +1 modest `I am not very good at explaining codes, but feel free to ask if you need more details.`

Answer (score 0):

instead of sorting array, try to write the query which will return sorted value.

e.g.  "select sizetype, price, From Product group by(saleprice)";

Comment: I'm not looking for work arounds, my code requires that I use this method.

Comment: This is _not_ a workaround, but a proper way to solve the problem you are having. MySQL search query will work a lot faster than the php after search.